# Why is page spinner JavaScript not working in IE11, but works in Chrome and FireFox?

Tags: javascript

I put together a Vanilla JavaScript function that checks to see if elements on the page are loaded within X seconds (`var timerDelay`), and after X seconds if DOM elements are still loading, a loader spinner is shown (`<div class="psspinner"></div>`). Once all DOM elements have finished loading, remove the spinner from the DOM. What I've put together seems to work fine in Chrome and FireFox, but not in Internet Explorer 11.

I've remade the script using jQuery since it doesn't work in IE11 with Vanilla JS. Since this script is responsible for checking if all DOM elements are loaded on the page or not, using jQuery is counterproductive because it relies on the jQuery library to load before the script will fire. Using Vanilla JS does not rely on a library, and would load much faster.

I'm not sure why the below function doesn't work in IE11. I've tried a combination of things, such as swapping out `querySelectorAll` with `getElementsByClassName`, but nothing I've tried works. Any suggestions?

Here is a JS Fiddle for providing the code in a dev environment: https://jsfiddle.net/7f1hhezs/

**Plain JS Version:**

```
/**
 * Page Load Spinner
 * - Add Spinner to DOM
 * - Vanilla JS
 */
function pSpinner() {
    var timerDelay = 0;
    var spinnerHtml = '<div class="pspinner"></div>';

    // Append HTML to body
    var appendSpinner = document.body.innerHTML += spinnerHtml;

    // Initiating setTimeout before showing spinner
    setTimeout(function () {

        if (document.querySelectorAll('.pspinner').length > 0) {
            console.log('loaded');

            document.querySelector('.pspinner').setAttribute('style', 'display: block; opacity: 1.00;');
        } else {
            console.log('false');

            return false;
        }
    }, timerDelay);

    // Remove spinner once DOM load completes
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        var removeElem = document.querySelectorAll('.pspinner')[0];
        removeElem.parentNode.removeChild(removeElem);
    });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    pSpinner();
});
```

**jQuery Version:**

```
/**
 * Page Load Spinner
 * - Add Spinner to DOM
 * - jQuery
 */
function pSpinner() {
    var timerDelay = 2500;
    var spinnerHtml = '<div class="pspinner"></div>';
    var spinnerSel = $('.pspinner');

    // Append HTML to body
    var appendSpinner = $('body').append(spinnerHtml);

    // Initiating setTimeout before showing spinner
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.pspinner').css({ display: 'block' });
        $('.pspinner').animate({ opacity: 1.00 }, 150);
    }, timerDelay);

    // Remove spinner once DOM load completes
    //window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        $('.pspinner').remove();
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){ pSpinner(); });
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? Did you add console.log lines to figure out what is not being called?

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but `document.querySelectorAll('.pspinner')[0]` can be replaced with `document.querySelector('.pspinner')`. Similar optimisations can be made in the `setTimeout` callback, which appears to be querying for '.pspinner' multiple times.

Comment: Hi epascarello, yes, I added console.logs, and no errors are appearing. I did add console.logs throughout the entire function process, numbering 1 - 8. In Chrome and FF, the ordered sequence for the numbers is the same, but different in IE. IE always hits false for the if condition (never the true condition) inside `setTimeout`, whereas Chrome and FF both hit the true condition.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions Chris. I definitely welcome any modifications I can make to optimize the script.

Comment: Such convoluted design. Why not have the spinner in the html (hiding everything but the spinner) and remove it once the document fully loads?

Comment: Very unhelpful Majid. Maybe the design is convoluted according to you, but that is not the problem. You're suggesting that I change my approach of where to put the spinner, and then remove the spinner once the document fully loads. But this is what is being done now, except that I am adding the spinner using JS instead of sticking the spinner in the HTML before the JS loads. How does your comment help? Your comment doesn't address my problem at all.

Answer (score 2):

> ***There Is No Issue With Your Script, Your CSS Is The Problem***

Your script is absolutely fine You can try it by commenting out that event listener for load. You can't see why page loader is not being showed because IE is little different(by little, I refer to your case, in my opinion IE is just another from another Kingdom (kingdom of living things, "yeah I am talking Biology"). DOMContentLoaded is fired either after the load event (I am talking few MS) or few ms before either ways, Your CSS does not work in IE-11, But that is not related, you might want to change tag to CSS. and yeah I changed your code A little bit, umm cleaned it a little bit if you may;

```
var spinnerHtml = '<div class="pspinner"></div>';
document.body.innerHTML += spinnerHtml;
var spinner = document.querySelector('.pspinner');
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function pSpinner() {
    var timerDelay = 0;
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (spinner) {
            console.log('loaded');
            spinner.setAttribute('style', 'display: block; opacity: 1.00;');
        } else {
            console.log('false');
            return false;
        }
    }, timerDelay);
});
//try commenting out code below you'll know function is running
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    spinner.parentNode.removeChild(spinner);
});
```

Here You go! I'm *not an expert* it can be ***optimized much*** by leaps and bound and ***different approach*** can be applied to solve this problem, and to do ***same task much efficiently***, but topic isn't about optimization it is **"Why your script isn't working"**. ***Your script is working*** your CSS animations are not!